# Toggle menu using javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to have toggle-open listen for a click and then CHANGE the class name of toggle-box to 'open'. And then have toggle-close listen fora a click and then CHANGE the class name of toggle-box to 'close'. Here is the code that I have already and it's not working, any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Drop Down</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dropdown.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="toggle-box" class="close">
    <div id="toggle-open">Settings</div>
    <div id="toggle-close">Close</div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="s-1">
                <input id="s-1" type="checkbox" checked>
                <span>Setting One</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="s-2">
                <input id="s-2" type="checkbox" checked>
                <span>Setting Two</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="s-3">
                <input id="s-3" type="checkbox">
                <span>Setting Three</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="s-4">
                <input id="s-4" type="checkbox" checked>
                <span>Setting Four</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="s-5">
                <input id="s-5" type="checkbox">
                <span>Setting Five</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; font-size: 75%;"><a href="../dropdown.zip">Download the files (dropdown.zip)</a></p>
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>
</body>
```

>

Comment: Any reason you're not referencing `dropdown.js` in your `<head>` instead of the `<body>`?

Comment: no there is no reason for that. I simply just need the functions to work as I explained.

Comment: Can you add your javascript in the question, as well as any debugging output?

Comment: it's good practice to add js files at the bottom of the body

Comment: Ok, can you answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add the [jquery](http://jquery.com) javascript library to your page (just one more <script> block) it can be done with the following javascript:

```
$("#toggle-open").click(function() {
  $("#toggle-box").attr("class", "open");
});
$("#toggle-close").click(function() {
  $("#toggle-box").attr("class", "close");
});
```

Without jquery:

```
document.getElementById("toggle-open").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("toggle-box").setAttribute("class", "open");
});
document.getElementById("toggle-close").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("toggle-box").setAttribute("class", "close");
});
```

Comment: I can't use any jquery it has to be all javascript.

Comment: just put the javascript inside a <script>...</script> block

Answer (score 0):

No need for jQuery.

```
var toggleBox = document.getElementById('toggle-box');

document.getElementById('toggle-open').click = function() {
  toggleBox.className = 'open';
};

document.getElementById('toggle-close').click = function() {
  toggleBox.className = 'close';
};
```

Comment: Does this go write into the HTML?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? This is javascript and therefore it must be in a `script` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the line:

```
<script src="dropdown.js"></script>
```

in your code you can write: (You can erase the lines that have alert(tooglebox.className); that I put just to test.)

```
<script>
var settings = document.getElementById('toggle-open');
var close = document.getElementById('toggle-close');
var tooglebox = document.getElementById('toggle-box');

settings.onclick = function(){
    tooglebox.className = "open";
    alert(tooglebox.className);
}    
close.onclick = function(){
    tooglebox.className = "close";
    alert(tooglebox.className);
}
</script>
```